# Select an autogenerated WebForm Control ID with JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

ASP.NET is auto generating an ID instead of using the one I assign.  How would I select this value using jQuery?  I am not trusting that the auto generated value would always be the same.

Here is my ASPX Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="short_width" MaxLength="10" />
```

Here is what is generated:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContentArea$txtZip" type="text" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_MainContentArea_txtZip" class="short_width" />
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#txtZip").mask("99999?-9999");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your javascript is in the `aspx` page you can use `ClientId`. Otherewise you'll have to use a class like in the other answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#<%=txtZip.ClientId%>").mask("99999?-9999");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that in web forms or I would have added it to my answer. +1. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid I try to forget about web forms everyday.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET 4 or above, maybe try using ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 5):

You can use the class selector:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".short_width").mask("99999?-9999");
});
```

I would create a new class i.e. zipCode and add it to your control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="short_width zipCode" MaxLength="10" />
```

Then use this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".zipCode").mask("99999?-9999");
});
```

That way it keeps it separate from your other styles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have other controls with the .short_width style on the screen, and they don't need the mask.

Comment: Good answer. You'll find that .NET wants to control all of the element IDs. You're better off using class names instead. You can use unique class names: CssClass="short_width zipcode"

Comment: I've updated it, I added that just while you posted the comments. @Diodeus Great minds think alike. :)

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4.5 has ClientIDMode property on controls, if you set it to static then the control's ID won't change from what you assign to it, it'll stay as txtZip.